# Solving integral using trig substitution $\tan(x/2)=t$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, partial-fractions, substitution

I have problems with solving the following integral:

$$ \int{{\sin x - \cos x}\over {\sin x + \cos x}} \, dx$$

Could anybody please help me to find the solution and show me the method how it can be solved? I already tried to solve similar ones but I get always stuck when trying the technique with partial fraction decomposition.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: What was your exact attempt? Where did you get stuck? And please use $\LaTeX$ next time.

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts. 
You are more likely to receive positive/constructive feedback that way.  
Formatting your post helps too. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: My answer doesn't tell you what the bottom line is, nor does it tell you how to evaluate the integral of the rational function that results from the substitution, but I think it gives a more detailed account of the substitution itself than the other answers do, and this particular substitution needs a fairly detailed account in order to be properly understood. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @addy2012 : It is at best very silly to call the math-notation typesetting software $\text{“}\LaTeX\text{''}$.  It is MathJax.  $\LaTeX$ doesn't just do mathematical notation, and that's not even most of what it does. People who master MathJax under the mistaken impression that they then know $\LaTeX$ are in for a shock if they try to use actual $\LaTeX$ and find they know next to nothing about it. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Do you think I do not know that? MathJax uses LateX for input. ok you could use MathML or sth else too, I guess. But most people use LaTeX' math syntax for setting formulas anyway.

Comment: @addy2012 : You may be well aware of it, but your comment may mislead others who will be shocked if they try to use actual $\LaTeX$ when they mistakenly think they know $\LaTeX$ when what they really know is MathJax. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'm sorry, but I think you're a little overreacting. I would not care about people believing they are $\LaTeX$ masters although they just use a math typesetting plugin ;)

Comment: `\relax`, please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing the half-angle substitution (per your title), you have
$$t=\tan\frac{x}{2}\implies\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{2}\sec^2\frac{x}{2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
From the fact that $t=\tan\dfrac{x}{2}$, you can extract the following:
$$\begin{cases}\sin x=2\sin\dfrac{x}{2}\cos\dfrac{x}{2}=\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}\\[1ex]
\cos x=\cos^2\dfrac{x}{2}-\sin^2\dfrac{x}{2}=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\\[1ex]
\sec^2\dfrac{x}{2}=1+t^2\end{cases}$$
All of this tells you your initial integral is equivalent to
$$\int\frac{\sin x-\cos x}{\sin x+\cos x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int\frac{\frac{2t}{1+t^2}-\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}{\frac{2t}{1+t^2}+\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}\times\frac{2}{1+t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=-2\int\frac{t^2+2t-1}{(t^2-2t-1)(1+t^2)}\,\mathrm{d}t$$
Decomposing into partial fractions yields
$$-2\int\left(\frac{t-1}{t^2-2t-1}-\frac{t}{t^2+1}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t$$
Both integrals can easily be computed with substitutions that use the integrand's term's respective denominators.

Answer (score 6):

$$\int\frac{\sin(x)-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=\sin(x)+\cos(x)$ and $\text{d}u=(\cos(x)-\sin(x))\space\text{d}x$:

---

$$-\int\frac{1}{u}\space\text{d}u=-\ln\left|u\right|+\text{C}=-\ln\left|\sin(x)+\cos(x)\right|+\text{C}$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

substitute $t=\sin x +\cos x$ and $dt=(\cos x - \sin x)dx$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\tan \frac x 2 & = t \\[8pt]
\frac x 2 & = \arctan t \\[8pt]
x & = 2\arctan t \\[8pt]
\sin x & = \sin(2\arctan t) = \sin(2 \, \bullet) = 2 \sin(\bullet)\cos(\bullet) \\
& = 2\sin(\arctan t)\cos(\arctan t), \\[8pt]
\cos x & = \cos(2\arctan t) = \cos(2\,\bullet) = \cos^2(\bullet) - \sin^2(\bullet) \\
& = \cos^2(\arctan t) - \sin^2(\arctan t).
\end{align}

Now let us consider what $\sin(\arctan t)$ and $\cos(\arctan t)$ are.

$\tan = \dfrac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}} = \dfrac t 1$ so $\text{hypotenuse} = \sqrt{t^2+1^2}$, and so we have
$$
\sin(\arctan t) = \frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}} = \frac t {\sqrt{t^2+1}}.
$$
Similarly
$$
\cos(\arctan t) = \frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}} = \frac 1 {\sqrt{t^2+1}}.
$$
Consequently
$$
2\sin(\arctan t)\cos(\arctan t) = 2\cdot \frac 1 {\sqrt{t^2+1}} \cdot \frac t {\sqrt{t^2+1}} = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}.
$$
Similarly
$$
\cos^2(\arctan t) - \sin^2(\arctan t) = \frac 1 {1+t^2} - \frac t {1+t^2} = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}.
$$
So now we have
$$
\left.
\begin{align}
\sin x & = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}, \\[10pt]
\cos x & = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}.
\end{align}
\right\} \tag 1
$$

Finally, since $x = 2\arctan t$, we have
$$
dx = \frac{2\,dx}{1+t^2}. \tag 2
$$

Your ultimate answer comes from $(1)$ and $(2)$, followed by actually evaluating the resulting integral of a rational function.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, $$\int \frac{\sin x-\cos x}{\sin x+\cos x}\ dx$$$$=\int \frac{-(\cos x-\sin x)}{\sin x+\cos x}dx $$
$$=-\int \frac{d(\sin x+\cos x)}{\sin x+\cos x} $$
$$=\color{red}{-\ln|\sin x+\cos x|+C}$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice, $$\int \frac{\sin x-\cos x}{\sin x+\cos x}\ dx$$
$$=\int \frac{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}-1}{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}+1}\ dx$$

$$=\int \frac{\tan x-1}{\tan x+1}\ dx$$

$$=\int \frac{\tan x-\tan\frac \pi4}{1+\tan x\tan\frac \pi4}\ dx$$
$$=\int\tan\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\ dx$$
$$=\color{blue}{\ln\sec\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+C}$$